# Display saved localstorage keys in div/table

Tags: load, key, local-storage

I've looked up and down and have found a few references to recovering localstorage key-value pairs and displaying them in tables/divs/lists/etc, but have had no luck on my end.

I have been able to save the key-value pairs as a string from form input fields into localstorage using json-stringify and have confirmed so with safari's web inspector/resource viewer.

My issue is displaying a representation of the key-value pair in a table/div/list so that the user can click on the saved key and reload the values into the form. The saved keys will not load into the div upon `updateJobsList()` but the console throws no errors so there must be something completely wrong.

Below is the pertinent sample code from my js file.

```
function updateJobsList() {
var jobs = localStorage.length
var s = '<h2>Jobs</h2>';
s+= '<ul>';
for (var i=0;i<jobs;i++) {
  var jobName = localStorage.key(i);
  s+= '<li>'+
      '<div style="float:right;">'+
      '<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="readLocal(\''+jobName+'\');"/'+'> '+
      '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteLocal(\''+jobName+'\');"/'+'> '+
      '</div>'+
      '<strong>'+jobName+'</strong>'+
      '</li>';
  }
  $('jobs').innerHTML = s+'</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to loop through localStorage as an iterative array, but the values in localStorage are stored as an associative array, using name/value pairs. The method for looping through an object or associative array is a bit different:

```
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    for (var key in storage) {
        var jobName= storage[key]);
        // execute the rest of your code
    }
```

Right, so that allows you to access the object values, but you still need to insert your html (stored in your variable "s") into the DOM. First define an element in your html and specify an id:

```
<div id="jobsList"></div>
```

Then, assuming you're using jQuery, you would fill the html element like this:

```
$("#jobsList").html(s);
```

Comment: I changed my loop to what you described and instead of displaying the key for the key-value pairs, it gave me the JSON string of values.

However, I did see something I did not have correct, I changed `$(jobsList).html();` to `$("#jobsList").html()` and my current script began displaying the keys in localstorage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(jobs).html();
```

is what you are looking for assuming you are using jQuery. also make sure you escape jobName in case it contains single or double quote

Comment: So ideally, this is the simplest way to get it to work?
`$(jobs).html(jobName);`
If so, that's also not working.